# Using the Box-Muller transform to generate pseudorandom numbers with any sigma and mean

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic

I'm trying to implement the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) to generate pseudorandom numbers with Gaussian distribution. Apparently, this method only generates numbers with sigma 1 and mean 0. How do I use it to generate numbers with arbitrary sigma and mean?

Comment: Just multiply by sigma and add mu.

Comment: You might look into the [log-polar method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method), which will likely be faster, unless you can call `fsincos` or `expi` in C or assembly.

Comment: @horchler: I think the more fundamental concept is that no matter what mechanism you use to you get your hands on a standard normal, it's a trivial transformation to turn it into a generic normal.

Answer (score 13):

There's no need for a separate method.  A well know result from statistics is that you can convert back and forth between a standard normal (Gaussian) value Z to a general Gaussian X with mean mu and standard deviation sigma by the simple transformation `X = sigma*Z + mu`, or vice-versa, `Z = (x - mu)/sigma`.  This is why statistics books only need/provide one table for the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Which is precisely what was described in the linked article. Box-Muller in itself generates a distribution with unit variance. While it's extremely simple to convert to a different distribution, it's not Box-Muller any more, it *is* a separate method, even if trivially different.

Comment: @JasonC: You're not converting to a different distribution. You're transforming to a different parameterization of the normal distribution. Knowing how to transform standard normals to arbitrary normals transcends whether the underlying normal came from a Box-Muller, polar, ziggurat, or other generator.

Answer (score 2):

Box-Muller generates distributions with unit variance, so the short answer to your question is: You don't use Box-Muller to generate numbers with arbitrary sigma.

The long answer, however, is brighter. [Here is a paper](http://www.alpheratz.net/murison/Maple/GaussianDistribution/GaussianDistribution.pdf) with a modified Box-Muller algorithm that supports arbitrary variance. It's very straightforward.

As for mean, that one's easy. Just add the mean to your result.

It boils down to what Lee Daniel Crocker mentioned in the comments; multiply by sigma and add the mean.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I'd upvote you, but I don't have enough points. I found code online that implements (the modified form of) the transformation. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function genererNombreLoiNormale($mu, $sigma) {

    // On récupère deux nombres pseudo-aléatoires indépendants selon une loi uniforme sur l'intervalle [0;1]
    $randNumUni = rand(0,999) / 1000;
    $randNumBi = rand(0,999) / 1000;

    // On récupère un nombre pseudo-aléatoire selon une loi normale centrée réduite
    // (Paramètres : moyenne = 0, écart-type = 1)
    // Utilisation de l'algorithme de Box-Muller
    $randNumNorm = sqrt(-2.0*log($randNumUni))*cos(( 2.0 * 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375 )*$randNumBi);

    return ($mu + $sigma * $randNumNorm);
}
```

// Il suffit de centrer la function sur une valeur $mu et de lui donner un écart $sigma pour s'approcher plus ou moins du centre de la function recherché

[A possible English translation: It's sufficient to center the function on a value $mu and give it a gap of size $sigma so that it will approach, to a greater or lesser degree, the center of the desired function.]

Comment: Can you post your comment in English?

Comment: You better translate this to English